# Find package dependencies from database table

Tags: database, sqlite, recursion

I have two tables in a database, one lists package and one lists dependencies:

```
packages

id | name
---------
 0 | xorg
 1 | gnome-session
 2 | gnome-panel
 3 | gnome-mixer-applet
 4 | gnome-media

depends

package | depends
-----------------
      1 | 0
      2 | 1
      3 | 2
      4 | 2
```

Obviously, if I want to find out what a package depends on, I can do:

```
SELECT *
  FROM packages
 INNER JOIN depends
    ON packages.id = depends.package
 WHERE packages.id = @somenumber
```

The problem is that this only gives me one level of dependencies (4 depends on 2, but it also depends on packages 1 and 0). Is there a way to get all of the dependencies without just running similar `SELECT`s in a loop?

I'd prefer that it works in SQLite, but I'll use a different database if I need to (as long as it's free and available on Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL is the only open-source RDBMS that supports [recursive queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html).  For example, you could run this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE package_deps(id) AS (
  SELECT d.package FROM depends d WHERE d.package = @startingnumber
  UNION ALL
  SELECT d.package FROM depends d JOIN package_deps pd ON d.depends = pd.id
)
SELECT p.* FROM package_deps pd JOIN packages p USING (id);
```

SQLite has no support for recursive queries, but there are several other solutions for managing hierarchical data in more plain SQL.  See my presentation [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data).

Comment: Very interesting. I'll have to try some of the patterns in your presentation.

Comment: I also cover tree-like data, and many other topics, in my new book *SQL Antipatterns*  :-) http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns